# dotnet core 2.0 mq, what to use？

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have an api that process some images and then upload the output image to 3-part storage service,  and finally get a url. The total process is a bit time cost, so I want to put the task in a message queue.
The question is, what message queue tech is ready here for use with asp.net core 2.0？

Is SignalR suit for only server side mq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SignalR` is not a good idea because `SignalR` using push mechanism to notify but it seems in your case some pull method is more suitable and also `SignalR` doesn't support really permanent queue to keep messages in queue while consumers being ready. I'm strongly recommend you to use `RabbitMQ` in this case, I've used `RabbitMQ` in my .net core 2 project and it working pretty well.